# How to change \hslash into Times-Roman font?

Tags: mtpro

Here's my input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMP2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP2}{mtt}{\skewchar\font48}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}{<-7> mt2syf <7-9> mt2sys <9-> mt2syt}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Test}     {LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\hslash}{\mathord}{Test}{175}

\begin{document}
Words $\hslash$ words.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not typing `\usepackage{mtpro2}` or, if you have the really old version of the MathTime Professional package, `\usepackage{mtpro}`?

Comment: Problem solved? Did the answer of user Mico help?

Comment: yes, the answer help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "lite" subset of the `mtpro2` ([MathTime Professional II](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html)) font package may be downloaded free of charge, I suggest you rewrite your example code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times} % or: \usepackage{newtxtext} %% Times Roman text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
Words $\hslash$ words.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, instead of loading the `times` and `mtpro2` packages, load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.